# MYSQL регулярное выражение - изъять строку

Tags: mysql

Произошла небольшая тех. авария на сайте - удалились файлы.

Благо есть все бекапы которые можно восстановить в автоматическом режиме. 
Для этого есть специальный код с предварительным MYSQL запросом - в него нужно прислать ID'ы файлов под которыми данные о них хранятся в БД.

Имеется таблица `logs` с записями которые содержат такое поле -

```
 | action |
 | dellfile_10563_cron |
```

(отличается только числа - это ID файла).

Для восстановления файлов как я говорил выше в запрос нужно прислать список ID's. Возможно ли это сделать средствами MYSQL, в одном запросе и только? Без внедрения PHP.

То есть чтобы вышел подобный запрос (нужно получить данные файлов для восстановления где ID равен числу между dellfile_ и _cron в logs - своего рода preg_match):

```
SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE id IN( SELECT action.dellfile_[0-9]+_cron FROM logs  )
```

Comment: Если у вас MySQL 8 версии, то есть функция regexp_substr. В остальных случаях предлагаю использовать substring_index и ориентироваться на подчеркивания